# Unable to access DOM elements in component during tests (works in the browser)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom

## Background

I have a component where I'm accessing an element's children (using a ref). The goal is to intercept a paste event into an input field and to split and distribute the pasted content over several uncontrolled form input elements. This all works fine when rendering the component in the browser (with Storybook).

## Problem

In tests, however, **I cannot access the children** in any way I try.

## Questions

- Is there something wrong with how I use `fireEvent` or how the test is set up?
- I'm pretty new to React, should I be accessing DOM elements some other way?
- Or should I simply not use testing-library to test this behaviour?

Any help would be hugely appreciated because I don't know what else to try at this point!

## Example

I've made a minimal example of a component that shows the problem.

### Component

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { prettyDOM } from "@testing-library/dom";


function Dummy({}) {
  const inputContainer = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    // The elements exist!
    console.log('document', prettyDOM(document))
    console.log('div', prettyDOM(inputContainer.current))
    console.log('e.target', prettyDOM(e.target))

    // All attempts to get the inputs return empty collections.
    console.log('div.children', inputContainer.current.children)
    console.log('div.childNodes', inputContainer.current.childNodes)
    console.log('div.querySelectorAll("*")', inputContainer.current.querySelectorAll("*"))
    console.log('e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll("input")', e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll("input"))

    // Going via the document doesn't work either...
    console.log('document.querySelectorAll("#outer input").children', document.querySelectorAll('#outer input'))

    // For some reason, firstChild works (but I need all children, not just one).
    console.log('div.firstChild', inputContainer.current.firstChild.value)
  };

  return (
    <fieldset id="outer">
      <div ref={inputContainer}>
        <input type="text" onClick={handleClick} defaultValue="bar"/>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  );
}

export default Dummy;
```

### Test

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/dom'
import Dummy from "./Dummy";


describe("Dummy", () => {
  it("should do something", () => {
    render(<Dummy />);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByDisplayValue("bar"));

    expect(false).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

### Jest output

```
 FAIL  src/components/Dummy.test.js
  Dummy
    ✕ should do something (96 ms)

  ● Dummy › should do something

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

      11 |     fireEvent.click(screen.getByDisplayValue("bar"));
      12 |
    > 13 |     expect(false).toBe(true);
         |                   ^
      14 |   });
      15 | });
      16 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Dummy.test.js:13:19)

  console.log
    document <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <div>
          <fieldset
            id="outer"
          >
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                value="bar"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
              />
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:11:13)

  console.log
    div <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value="bar"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
      />
    </div>

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:12:13)

  console.log
    e.target <input
      type="text"
      value="bar"
    />

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:13:13)

  console.log
    div.children HTMLCollection {}

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:16:13)

  console.log
    div.childNodes NodeList {}

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:17:13)

  console.log
    div.querySelectorAll("*") NodeList {}

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:18:13)

  console.log
    e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll("input") NodeList {}

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:19:13)

  console.log
    document.querySelectorAll("#outer input").children NodeList {}

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:22:13)

  console.log
    div.firstChild bar

      at handleClick (src/components/Dummy.js:25:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.995 s
Ran all test suites matching /dum/i.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Answer (score 1):

These

- `HTMLCollection {}`
- `NodeList {}`

are ***not*** empty lists! They are printed this way regardless of their contents! A list with 1 or 1,000 elements will be printed as `{}` (by jsdom, I assume?).

I sincerely hope this will help someone else save some time, because it sure cost me too much…