# Cannot query DOM from event handler in tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

How can I enable my components to access the DOM in tests?

In the browser, this component logs my `<div>` as expected:

```js
function Dummy() {
  const handleClick = (e) => console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div'));

  return <div onClick={handleClick}>Hello</div>;
}
```

But using this test, it just prints an empty NodeList:

```js
it("should do something", () => {
  render(<Dummy />);
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText("Hello"));
  expect(false).toBe(true);
});
```

How come? Am I missing some required test setup?

Comment: This is a simplified version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69251619/unable-to-access-dom-elements-in-component-during-tests-works-in-the-browser - I wasn't sure if I should leave both up or edit the original. Please let me know if I should take any action here!

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out it *doesn't* print an empty NodeList. It prints `NodeList {}`, which may *look* empty but in fact is also printed when there are items in the list…